# Ionic HTTP data return issue

Tags: json, http, ionic-framework

I'm learning all things Ionic. Typescript, Angular and a few other technologies constituting Ionic are all new to me.

Running the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CategoriesServiceProvider } from '../../providers/categories-service/categories-service';
import { CategoryPage } from '../category/category';

/**
 * Generated class for the CategoriesPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-categories',
  templateUrl: 'categories.html',
  providers: [CategoriesServiceProvider]
})
export class CategoriesPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private categories: CategoriesServiceProvider) {
  }

  quizCategories: any;

  getCategories(){
    this.categories.getCategories().then(question_categories => {
      if(question_categories.categories){
        this.quizCategories = question_categories.categories;
        console.log(this.quizCategories);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I added **line#28** in an attempt to check that *question_categories* is returning data but both that check and the assignment on **line#29** generate the same problem.

The json data I am attempting to read is as follows:

```
{
    "categories": 
    [
        {
            "category": {
                "name": "Level 1",
                "count": "1",
                "tid": "3"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "name": "Level 2",
                "count": "2",
                "tid": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is just a Typescript typing error. You should type the return value of `this.categories.getCategories()` according to the expected structure of your json.

Comment: The [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response) on this should get you started ;)